# Can you connect to a FVS336Gv2 without using VPN Lite Software?

Tags: vpn

My uncle purchased a [NETGEAR ProSafe FVS336Gv2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004Y16Y4C). Now we want to use the VPN functionality of it. I didn't see any mention on the box or the manual that we'd have to pay for a license to use their VPN client. Anyway, I don't want to pay for the license. [VPN Lite Software is just the VPN client-side connection stack for Windows.](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22873)

Is there anyway to connect to this VPN from any version of Windows that doesn't require the license? Is the license for the client, or the server-side connection?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This device supports regular, no-frills PPTP connections if you just want to use the built-in Windows VPN functionality.

I stopped buying the FVS range after Netgear were consistently poor with providing SSL VPN drivers for newer operating systems.

Comment: Is their branded client just a skin on top of OpenVPN? I've found that to be the case for several of these type products. In these cases, I've had some success just using the vanilla OpenVPN client.